# Using Python to parse pdf and extract Author and Book name

Tags: python, pdf, split

I have a Mailing Reference List in a form a pdf. The mailing list has a very general format i.e Author Name followed by the Name of the book.
Consider the following examples:

**American Reading List**

**Democratic Theory**

• Dahl, Preface to Democratic Theory

• Schumpeter, Capitalism, Socialism, and Democracy (Introduction and part IV only)

• Machperson, Life and Times of Liberal Democracy

• Dahl, Democracy and its Critics

Now I am trying to parse the pdf using pdf miner and create a list where in the first index is the author name and the second index is the name of the book just like this:

[Dahl, Preface to Democratic Theory]

I am trying to use the split functionality because there is a comma and a space followed by the Author name. However I don't get the correct results.
Can somebody help?

```
def extract():
    string = convert_pdf_to_txt("/Users/../../names.pdf")
    lines = list(filter(bool, string.split('\n')))
    for i in lines:
        check.extend(i.split(','))
    x=remove_numbers(check)
    remove_blank= [x for x in x if x]
    combine_two = [remove_blank[x:x + 2] for x in xrange(0,len(remove_blank), 2)]
    print combine_two
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what's going wrong here. I'm making some guesses, but hopefully they are the relevant ones.

1. Your `convert_pdf_to_text()` function returns a single long string containing all the text of the PDF.
2. You split the text on `", "` which results in a list of strings.

Given your example data, this list looks something like this (each element is on a separate line here):

```
Dahl
Preface to Democratic Theory(line break)(bullet)(tab)Schumpeter
Captitalism
Socialism
and Democracy (Introduction and part IV only)(line break)(bullet)(tab)Machpherson
Life and Times of Liberal Democracy(line break)(bullet)(tab)Dahl
Democracy and its Critics
```

Because you split on `", "` without regard for the fact that the data is formatted as lines, you end up with stuff from multiple lines in each item.

3. Now you use `filter()` to iterate over this list and filter out all the ones that aren't true. A non-empty string is true, and all of the elements are non-empty strings, so all the elements get through. Your `filter()` therefore doesn't do anything.

What you seem to want is something more like this:

```
lines = [line.split(", ", 1) for line in string.splitlines() if ", " in line]
```

Here we first split the lines, filter out any that don't have comma-space in them, and return a list of lists based on splitting the string on the first comma-space.

Comment: Hi kindall, Thanks for helping. But I am still not getting the right output. I am getting something like this : [['Dahl', 'Preface to Democratic TheorySchumpeter, Capitalism, Socialism, and Democracy (Introduction and part IV only)Machperson, Life and Times of Liberal DemocracyDahl, Democracy and its Critics']]

Comment: My guess is that your `convert_pdf_to_txt()` isn't including line breaks. Which, upon reflection, is probably because PDFs don't actually include line breaks (they just say "print this next bit here" and "here" happens to be at the beginning of the next line). Is there some other way you could detect where one item ends and the next begins? Does it include the bullets? If so, you could try splitting on those.

Comment: I have somehow used the new line split functionality to achieve the results. However, on trying to combine the author name and book name, by making a separate list of every first and second element of the bigger list, I ran into a problem. The heading comes along with the author names.. Here is a snippet of results : 
[['American Reading List  ', 'Revised //'], ['Democratic Theory', 'Madison'], [' Federalist ', ' '], ['Dahl', ' Preface to Democratic Theory']

Comment: Can we do something to remove the headings??

Comment: I'd think that he bit in my answer about filtering out the lines that don't have ", " in them should handle that...